# Which Openssl version compatible with Indy 10 version 5519 and 5438?

Tags: indy10, delphi-5

I use Indy 10 build 5438 under Delphi 5 with OpenSSL 1.0.2m.

There is some problem with TLS v1.2 e-mail sending with some (not all) e-mail accounts, and I want to try to upgrade the OpenSSL DLL files for Indy 10, but I do not know which one is compatible.

Which is the latest(!) OpenSSL version that is compatible with Indy 10 build 5438?

I already tried to install the latest Indy 10 build 5519 under Delphi 5 with `fulld_5.bat`, but it failed:

```
IdIMAP4.pas(2958) Error: Undeclared identifier: 'LLTextBuf'

IdIMAP4.pas(2958) Error: Incompatible types

IdIMAP4.pas(3185) 
IdIMAP4.pas(3697) 
IdIMAP4.pas(4209) 
IdIMAP4.pas(4721) 
IdIMAP4.pas(5233) 
IdIMAP4.pas(5745) 
IdIMAP4.pas(6257) 
IdIMAP4.pas(6769) 
IdIMAP4.pas(7251) 

IndyProtocols50.dpk(267) Fatal: Could not compile used unit 'IdIMAP4.pas'
Error!
```

Comment: Where can I download an earlier version of Indy 10? (Like newer then 5438, but older then 5519)

Comment: the build number is an SVN revision number. You would have to download specific revisions from [Indy's SVN server](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx) directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy 10 uses standard OpenSSL DLLs. Any 1.0.2 version of OpenSSL is compatible with Indy ([Indy does not support OpenSSL 1.1.x yet](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183)). However, pre-built versions of OpenSSL <sup>1</sup> (built without MS Visual C++ runtime dependencies) are available on Indy's Fulgan mirror:

https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL

<sup>1: At the time of this writing, the latest version available there is 1.0.2t.</sup>

As for the `IdIMAP4.pas` error, that was a typo in a recent code checkin. On line 2958, the reference to `LLTextBuf` needs to be changed to `LTextBuf` instead.

```pascal
LUseNonSyncLiteral := LCanUseNonSyncLiteral and ((not LNonSyncLiteralIsLimited) or (Length({LLTextBuf}LTextBuf) <= 4096)); // <-- change LLTextBuf to LTextBuf
```

I have now fixed that in the official Indy code (SVN revision 5520).

Comment: Thank you Remy! I fix the typo and recompile works, now I am using the latest Indy 10 now with Delphi 5 (because my own old source codes)!

Comment: @peteri77 I have just now checked in a fix for the `IdIMAP4.pas` error to Indy's SVN.